# Show that the center of the circle $(ABC) $ is on $AE $.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $\triangle   ABC $ and $D\in [BC] $ s.t. $\angle BAD=\angle DAC $.

Let $BE\perp AD $ where $E $ is on the circle (ABD).

Show that the center of the circle $(ABC) $ is on $AE $.

I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Angle chasing is enough for this problem:

$$\angle ABE = 90^\circ - \angle BAD = 90^\circ - \frac A2,$$
where $A$ denotes the angle at $A$ of $\triangle ABC$. Now 
$$ \begin{aligned}\angle DAE &= \angle BDE = B - \angle ABE\\
&= B - (90^\circ - A/2)\\
&= B + A/2 - 90^\circ
\end{aligned}$$
so 
$$ \begin{aligned}
\angle BAE &= A/2 + \angle DAE\\
&= B + A - 90^\circ\\
&= 90^\circ - C.
\end{aligned}$$

It remains to show that $\angle BAO = 90^\circ - C$ which is obvious.

Note: Of course we need to consider the case where $C > 90^\circ$, but it would be very similar.